# How to build a linux kernel with -generic suffix?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, buildroot

I'm trying to build linux kernel for arm64 using buildroot. All my builds end without -generic suffix (uname -r ) but when I checked official ubuntu kernel they end with -generic. I searched buildroot manual etc. but I couldn't find related information.

So how can I build a generic kernel ?

Comment: You should check the kernel building tools of Ubuntu. "generic" is one of their notation. I think they use a "generic" .config file

Comment: Thanks. I could find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This additional -generic string is not very important, it's just a free form string that you can append to the kernel version. This free form string is specified in the kernel configuration, with the `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION` option.